# What are the main issues limiting resolution of gamma ray detectors?

Tags: astronomy, particle-detectors, gamma-rays

Current gamma ray detector resolution is far from diffraction limited. For example, Swift's Burst Alert Telescope has a resolution of 1-4 arcminutes for gamma ray bursts ([Wikipedia:Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_Gamma-Ray_Burst_Mission#Burst_Alert_Telescope_.28BAT.29)).

My understanding is that the gamma ray flux from extrasolar sources is small, requiring a large aperture and exposure time.

Are there additional challenges specific to gamma rays? What can we expect from upcoming generations of detectors?

Comment: Currently the only insurmountable problem with these detectors is the US dollar. We don't have enough of them. That, however, is a problem you have to ask about in the economics and political science department. :-)  For a technological discussion see e.g. "The future of gamma-ray astronomy" by Juergen Knoedlseder, arXiv:1602.02728v1. Technologically these telescopes are pretty straight forward, however, in order to increase resolution, they have to be made larger (surprise!) and be equipped with more active sensing elements, which requires more mass and higher power consumption.

Comment: The resolution for x-ray telescopes is, by the way, already comparable to the resolution of small optical telescopes, see e.g. "High-resolution x-ray telescopes" by Stephen L. O‘Dell et al.. The problem there is probably launch mass and instrument size for the necessary increase in mirror thickness and size. One may have to chose a free flying configuration for the largest possible instruments (focal length!), but that's no different from optical telescopes.

Comment: There is also the issue of using something akin to mirrors/lenses with such photons, since they tend to destroy rather than refract in many materials.  For lower energy photons (e.g., X-rays) they can make small "adjustments" to the photon's trajectory and direct it towards a sensor but for something like a TeV gamma-ray, you can only determine the trajectory by using something like a shielded telescope.  Then you run into mass and financial constraints as CuriousOne already pointed out.